# 3rd Party AirPlay Video Quality

Tags: video, appletv, airplay, streaming

Apple's product page for AirPlay [states](https://www.apple.com/airplay/) that Apple TV 4K supports streaming "4K HDR video at 60 frames per second". However, I can't seem to find any other information about AirPlay video quality, especially for other devices.

Specifically, what is the supported resolution/HDR/framerate for 3rd party TVs streaming via the Apple TV app? Does it depend on the device? What are the network requirements, requirements for the source device, etc.?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of streaming you're talking about specifically? - Is this about mirroring the contents of an iPad or computer over AirPlay directly to a TV? - Or is this about playing moves/series using the AppleTV app running on a Smart TV? Exactly what TV are you using?

Comment: I am talking about about screen mirroring, and I'm wondering about the Apple TV app for smart TVs in general (and wondering if/how it varies from TV to TV).

Comment: Which TV specifically are you talking about? There’s no “in general” for smart TVs unfortunately - some have lots of processing power, some are really slow.

Comment: I am trying to buy a TV and I am curious how well AirPlay mirroring will work, mainly to see if it's worth getting an Apple TV 4K separately or not. No particular brand. Manufacturers don't seem to list AirPlay mirroring performance in the TV specs obviously, so I am trying to figure out how to figure that out (if that's possible).

Comment: I would advise reading reviews for the TVs in advance to have something to base your choice on, and then try it out in store before buying. In my opinion, the Apple TV 4K experience is much better than these smart TVs. For example I have a 2021-model Samsung, but AirPlay performance is slow and hard to use properly (I.e. multi view getting in the way). I connect an Apple TV 4K externally